# How to embed existing website in my Drupal 8 site?

Tags: 8, subsites

I have a site I created with Drupal 8, lets say http://falzon.xyz/.
Elsewhere, I have a site created with [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/), a bunch of static pages linked to each other visible http://www.elina-noe.eu/).
I'd like to "embed" the static site as a "subsite" of falzon.xyz, i.e. accessible as http://falzon.xyz/elina-noe/, by 'simply' putting all its files in a subfolder of the D8 site.
How can I do that?

Comment: Using @GiorgosK's advice, it's working! Anybody having the base URL (http://falzon.xyz/elina-noe/) is able to navigate this 'subsite'. How can I limit the access to the users of my 'root' site (i.e. http://falzon.xyz/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a subfolder inside your `docroot` folder such as `docroot/elina-noe` should suffice.

Put all the subsite files into this folder and if there is a `index.html` you can access your subsite just by visiting the subfolder `http://falzon.xyz/elina-noe/`

Comment: The caveat here is your web server is configured to use `index.html` when a dir path is requested. Many default web server configs do this, but just FYI in case you see otherwise.

Comment: @GiorgosK I come back on this (old) topic to ask a new question: is there a way to restrict the access to this "subsite" to the actual users allowed to the main Drupal site?

Comment: I don't think I have the answer to it and I am not sure it is such an easy question, perhaps create a new question for that @gbmapo

Comment: @GiorgosK Finally, I put one .htaccess file in elina-noe subfolder with `RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" !^http://www\.falzon\.xyz [NC]`and `RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]`in it and it seems to work.